# Where can I download IEDriverServer for Selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I was looking in the official website, but they always redirect me to here http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Where do they keep the IEDriverServer.exe latest version ?

Comment: What happens when you click on the "downloads_location" link on that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the URL for Selenium Downloads:  http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Latest releases:  http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Current release 2.42: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/